# Duplicated classes in Intellij IDEA when using Android Annotations

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-annotations

I'm using Intellij IDEA and Android Annotations in my android project. How can I avoid this little annoying thing when I have to delete manually autogenerated classes before rebuilding project?

This is an error I'm talking about

[image]

To make it work I have to delete manually classes which was generated by Android Annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem will be fixed in IDEA 12.0.1.

Workaround for 12.0 build: explicitly exclude the root with the generated sources from compilation. You can do it in `Settings` | `Compiler` | **Excludes**.

Comment: That helps a little bit, but there is another little annoying thing, that when there were some changes in autogenerated classes I have to manually synchronize folder where generated classes are stored.

Comment: you should configure aa to generate file in a subfolder of your main "gen" folder so that intellij can see the aa generated files.